# Поиск по архиву писем в Outlook с помощью Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Есть определенный архив писем Outlook, сохраненный на локальной папке на компьютере. С помощью Excel VBA нужно осуществить поиск по этому архиву по словам (по телу(!) письма), которые пользователь должен указывать сам, чтобы была также возможность провалиться в переписку, а не только в отдельные сообщения. В интернете есть что-то подобное, но с архивами, которые просто являются папкой в Outlook.

Comment: Объекты Outlook не станут работать с неприсоединённым архивом.

Comment: Его же можно предварительно подгрузить для этих целей

Comment: Ну присоединяйте, какие проблемы-то? Объектная модель Outlook доступна в MSDN.